# org.json.jsonexception: value... of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted into jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, json

i am following a tutorial and as far as i can tell i have done everything right ac-coding to it. however i keep getting an error in log cat that says

```
 org.json.jsonexception: value... of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted into jsonarray
```

i know may question on this have been asked but none of them seem to meet the problem i have.
my JSONParser class

```
 package com.nangu.r.a.t.s.JSONParser;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    public JSONArray GetDriverDetails(int driver_id)
    {
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/www.ratsa.com/New_folder/refatted_db/get_driver_details.php?driver_id="+driver_id;


        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                if(httpEntity != null){
                    try{
                        String enttityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                        Log.e("Entity Response : ",enttityResponse);

                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(enttityResponse);
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        return jsonArray;
        }


}
```

and my mainactivity

```
  package com.nangu.r.a.t.s;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import com.nangu.r.a.t.s.JSONParser.JSONParser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button scanBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, resultTxt;
    String scanContent;
    EditText etDriverId;
    int driver_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        resultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        etDriverId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverId);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnScan) {

            /*
             * IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
             * scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
             */
            scanContent = etDriverId.getText().toString();
            driver_id = Integer.parseInt(scanContent);


                //this means the did is assigned.
                new GetDriverDetails().execute(new JSONParser());


        }
    }

    public class GetDriverDetails extends AsyncTask<JSONParser, Long, JSONArray>
    {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(JSONParser... params) {
            //this is done in background thread
            return params[0].GetDriverDetails(driver_id);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            try{
                JSONObject driver = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


                resultTxt.setText(driver.getString("driver_first_name"));

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            // contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }


}
```

i would really be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

logcat with Entity Response:

```
04-13 23:40:17.768: E/Entity Response :(593): {"success":1,"driver":[{"driver_id":"1","driver_first_name":"Nangulukila ","driver_last_name":"Hacinzobolo","licence_class":"c","driver_dob":"1992-05-16","driver_adrress":"43 mulilansolo riverside","reg_date":"2011-04-05","reg_expiry":"2015-05-16"}]}
04-13 23:40:17.788: W/System.err(593): org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":1,"driver":[{"licence_class":"c","reg_expiry":"2015-05-16","driver_last_name":"Hacinzobolo","driver_dob":"1992-05-16","driver_id":"1","reg_date":"2011-04-05","driver_adrress":"43 mulilansolo riverside","driver_first_name":"Nangulukila "}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: please post the value of enttityResponse variable. it is clearly a json exception

Comment: you should probably use  jsonObject = new JSONObject(enttityResponse); instead of jsonArray = new JSONArray(enttityResponse);

Comment: Amir when i change that i get a mismatch error again at the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guy found the problem.... it was in my php script silly mistake i was using a scriptwritten for a different project...